# WCAG - How to make the screen reader read all the page automatically?

Tags: html, web, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I need to have a screen in my app which all of it's content will be read using the screen reader automatically.

I tried to add `role="dialog" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"` and it didn't make it.

I also tried to use `role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"` it did read it, but using 'alert' as prefix.

How can I make it happened using no prefixes and additional info ?

Comment: care to elaborate on why you need this please? Knowing your use case is important to know what solution to offer you (or whether you actually need a solution or a slight rethink of design). I can't think of a use case for a whole screen to have to be read automatically, more often than not there is a better method when people want something like this (but I could be wrong!).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `document` role is the correct one to use in your case. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Document_Role):

> Generally used in complex composite widgets or applications, the document role can inform assistive technologies to switch context to a reading mode: The document role tells assistive technologies with reading or browse modes to use the document mode to read the content contained within this element.

<s>You should include `tabindex="0"` on the element in which you wish to be immediately read, and use `JavaScript` to set the focus to the element.</s>

**Update**

I tested the following code in Mac/Chrome, version 79.0.3945.88, and removed the `tabindex` attribute as well as all `JavaScript`. `VoiceOver` immediately read the contents of the document in its natural order.

```
<div class="container" role="document">
  <p>
    Read this first.
  </p>
  <p>
    Read this next.
  </p>
</div>
```

I did a screen capture of the VoiceOver utility as it was reading the above `HTML` to show it working on page load (forgive the Giphy Capture bit at the beginning of the gif).

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me. 
I don't it should have too many work, like adding focus in `JS` it should read it in natural order

Comment: Remains the same, do we have some other options to implement it ?

Comment: @roeygol I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: document role should **only** be used in the context of application-mode (aka forms-mode) content. And the element with document role **should** have a tabindex, otherwise there would be no way of focusing on it. When it gets focus, the screen reader will treat the nested document as 'browsable' content (headings, lists etc.). Just be careful not to put any operable content inside there (such as buttons or menus), or they will almost certainly put the screen reader back into application mode.

Answer (score 0):

If this really is something like a dialog - which means it consists mostly of operable content (UI controls such as buttons) then the **non-operable** content **will not get announced** by default. You can solve this if, on the thing with `role="dialog"`, you have `aria-labelledby` pointing at its heading, and `aria-describedby` pointing at all the ids (space-separated) of the elements inside that you want read-out when it opens.

The markup might look like this:

```
<div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogheading" aria-describedby="foo bar">
<h2 id="dialogheading">Let's have a dialog</h2>
<p id="foo">lorem ipsum</p>
<p id="bar">rhubarb rhubarb</p>
<button>yadda</button>
<button>yoda</button>
</div>
```

If there's really a lot of non-operable content, or if there's no operable content, role dialog is the wrong thing. If the context for this 'screen' is in forms/application mode use `role=document` instead, and make sure it has a tabindex so you can give it focus, which should switch the screen reader to browse mode.